# Run latex within Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex

I used to launch `latex` within `Emacs` on a `.tex` file by `C-c C-c`.

I just changed my machine, and need to reconfigure all. I have already installed `texlive-full`, and copied `.emacs` from the previous machine to the new machine.

When I open a `.tex` file under `Emacs`, launch `C-c C-c`, and then type `LaTeX`, it opens another buffer, named `*tex-shell*`, and looks like as so:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what happened?

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 11.10 as virtual machine...

Comment: looks like you got vim running inside an emacs buffer

Comment: well this is vim for sure... apparently your emacs is configured to run vim instead of a latex compiler

Comment: Sounds like you were using Auctex before

Comment: You should show the beginning of the tex-shell buffer: it's probably
where we have the better chance to know what really happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really now what happen, but it seem you want to use auctex:

```
sudo apt-get install auctex
```

and relaunch Emacs should solve your problem.